# Grouping and outputting text to csv

Tags: python, regex, csv

I'd like to find the device address, usb port, and number of times the error occurs from the following sample data:

Here's what I have so far:

```
import re
import csv

f = open("file.txt", "r")

searchlines = f.readlines()                   
f.close()

for element in searchlines:

     usbPres = re.search('(USB)',element) #pattern to find usb lines
     devAddr = re.search('(address)\s\d+',element) #parsing pattern for device address
     port = re.search('(port)\s\d',element) #parsing pattern for port
     if usbPres:
```

This is where I get lost because I want to assign the correct port to device address and then count number of time it failed before a new device is inserted into that port and then write that to a CSV file.

**Expected output would be**
`DevicAddr    Port         Number of failed attempts
42            3              5

47            7              2

52            7              1`

"**Sample data**"

```
enter code here

[11883.112089] hub 1-0:1.0: Cannot enable port 3. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[11883.224080] usb 1-7: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 42
[11883.328151] hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 3
[11904.472097] hub 1-0:1.0: Cannot enable port 3. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[11907.440096] hub 1-0:1.0: Cannot enable port 3. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[11910.408093] hub 1-0:1.0: Cannot enable port 3. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[11913.376095] hub 1-0:1.0: Cannot enable port 3. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[11913.616090] usb 1-7: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 47

[11913.716121] hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 7

[11927.340096] hub 1-0:1.0: Cannot enable port 3. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[11930.308096] hub 1-0:1.0: Cannot enable port 7. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[11933.276124] hub 1-0:1.0: Cannot enable port 7. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[11934.224080] usb 1-7: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 52
[11936.244118] hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 7 is bad?
[11939.212116] hub 1-0:1.0: Cannot enable port 7. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
```

Comment: Could you provide some expected output?

Comment: Sorry about that output  entered

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading your example input and output correctly, there should actually be 6 failed attempts for device address 42 port 3. It seems we can get a delayed print of the failed attempt even though it started already on the next address and port.

Either way, the below code worked and caught the 6 attempts and ignored the first few that didn't have a start to them. I'm using a dictionary to map from a unique combination of address and port to number of failed attempts. If such a  pairing isn't unique but you want to distinguish between attempts of the same pair of address and port you will need to add a unique identifier as each pair is encountered. If you have any more questions about the answer let me know.

```
import os
import argparse
import operator
import re

def main():
    p = argparse.ArgumentParser (description="Creates a csv file report on data file.")
    p.add_argument("datafile", help="Path of data")
    p.add_argument("outfile", help="Path of new file.")
    args = p.parse_args()

    with open(args.datafile) as f:
        lines = f.read().splitlines()

    port_to_addr = dict()
    port_addr_to_count = dict()
    current_port = 'default'
    current_addr = 'default'
    for line in lines:
        usbPres = re.search("USB",line)
        if usbPres:
            devAddr = re.search("address\s(\d+)", line)
            beginEnumerate = re.search("enumerate", line)
            port = re.search("port\s(\d+)", line)

            if devAddr:
                current_addr = devAddr.group(1)
            elif beginEnumerate and port:
                current_port = port.group(1)
                port_to_addr[current_port] = current_addr
                port_addr_to_count[(current_port, port_to_addr[current_port])] = 1
            elif port:
                current_port = port.group(1)
                if current_port in port_to_addr and (current_port, port_to_addr[current_port]) in port_addr_to_count:
                    port_addr_to_count[(current_port, port_to_addr[current_port])] += 1

    header_row = ["DevicAddr", "Port", "Number of failed attempts"]
    rows = []
    for (port, addr) in port_addr_to_count:
        rows.append([addr, port, str(port_addr_to_count[(port, addr)])])

    rows.sort()
    rows.insert(0,header_row)

    newfile_lines = [",".join(row) + "\n" for row in rows]

    with open(args.outfile, 'w') as f:
        f.writelines(newfile_lines)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The output after running on your sample data was:

```
DevicAddr,Port,Number of failed attempts
42,3,6
47,7,3
52,7,2
```

Comment: This looks great but when I run it with the externaI file I get error: too few arguments. I changed datafile and outfile to the Input and Output files. What am I missing ? Is args.datafile need to be changed aswell?

Comment: If you're running this code exactly try running it with `-h`. You'll see you need to give it an input file to run on and the name of where to save the output csv file (remember to give full name with csv extension). It doesn't print to terminal. You can change that per your needs.

Comment: If you save this code as `countFailedAttempts.py` and the data as `SampleData.txt` and you want to create a file called `FailedAttempts.csv` then in the terminal your run command look like this: `python countFailedAttempts.py SampleData.txt FailedAttempts.csv`.